# Expectation and variance for a series of non IID Bernoulli variables each multiplied by some value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have $N$ machines, each of which produce $M1, M2, ..., M_N$ widgets per day, and each has a different likelihood of failing on any particular day, given by $P1, P2, ..., P_N$. How is the resulting random variable distributed? I'd like to be able to give a confidence interval for how many fewer widgets I'm likely to produce.

It's simple enough to use a Poisson Binomial to determine *how many* machines might fail in a given day, but since each produces a different number of widgets per day I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: What is the random variable? Number of widgets produced per day? With [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function), do you mean the [success probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution)?

Comment: @matija Yes I would like to specify widgets produced per day. Not certain which likelihood you're confused about. If you're confused by $P_i$ then yes, that is success probability.

Comment: @bendl What about the multinomial distribution?

Comment: The multinomial distribution is the law of a sum of iid random variables with finite support. In this case, the random variables are not iid.

Comment: @Matija The $p_i$'s are different at the multinomial distribution.

Comment: A [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) is given by $p_1,\dots,p_k$ and a number $n$ of trials, where $\sum_ip_i=1$. Here, we have probabilities $p_1,\dots,p_N$. Machine $i$ fails with probability $p_i$. In the extreme cases all machines could definitely fail, so all $p_i=1$, or definitely work, so all $p_i=0$. They don't have to sum up to $1$. If you're still not convinced notice that we need $k=N$, the number of $p_i$'s. What is the number $n$ of trials then?

Comment: What happens if a machine fails? Does it produce no widgets at all?

Comment: @PhoemueX that is the assumption that I assumed would make this as simple as possible. If having a random discount to the number of produced widgets that is defined by some (probably normal) distribution would potentially remove the combinatorics headache that Matija referenced in their answer, then I'm happy to entertain that option

Comment: In fact, the data I have includes a *weighted* probability of failure which takes into account the expected and actual output of my machines. For example if 10% of the time machine 2 works at half speed, I have data which tells me that its availability is 5%

Answer (score 1):

Let $F=(F_i)_{i=1,\dots,N}$ be independent Bernoulli variables with success probability $p_i$, so $F_i$ indicates if machine $i$ fails. Say that machine $i$ produces $m_i$ widgets per day. Let $s=\sum_im_i$ be the maximum possible number of widgets produced per day. For a number $n$ let $\mathcal F_n=\{f\in\{0,1\}^N:s-\sum_{i}f_im_i=n\}$ be the set of configurations $f\in\mathcal F_n$ for which exactly $n$ widgets are produced, since $n=s-\sum_if_im_i=\sum_i(1-f_i)m_i$ is indeed the total number of widgets produced by working machines. Analogously, the random variable $X=s-\sum_iF_im_i$ is the random number of widgets produced today. This gives
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X=n)&=\sum_{f\in\mathcal F_n}\mathbb P(F=f)=\sum_{f\in\mathcal F_n}\prod_{i\in f^{-1}(1)}p_i\prod_{i\in f^{-1}(0)}(1-p_i),
\end{align*}
where $f^{-1}(1)=\{i:f_i=1\}$ and $f^{-1}(0)=\{i:f_i=0\}$.

In words, we consider all configurations $f$ for which we obtain exactly $n$ working widgets (which may be none, one or more, in general $|\mathcal F_n|$) and sum up their probabilities to obtain the probability for the desired outcome $n$. In this generality, there is no better way to put it, meaning something like the binomial distribution. Already the mere task of deciding which numbers $n$ are in the support, i.e. have positive probability, is rather demanding. With some additional discussion one can observe that they have to be on a certain *lattice* given by the *greatest common divisor* of the $m_i$. If you're interested in the variance for the confidence interval, however, this can be easily determined due to the independence of the $F_i$. Recall that the variance of $1-F_i$ is $p_i(1-p_i)$, that $X=\sum_i(1-F_i)m_i$, that the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances given independence, that the variance of $aY$ is $a^2$ times the variance of a random variable $Y$, and hence the variance of $X$ is $\sum_im_i^2p_i(1-p_i)$. Of course, the expectation is $\sum_im_i(1-p_i)$.